# Dynamically build up a SASS map and then use the values

Tags: css, sass

Based upon some simple SASS logic, I'm trying to generate a list or map of colors dynamically. Starting with a static list first:

```
$mypalette: (
   'jungle':    $color-green,
   'sky':       $color-blue,
   'sunset':    $color-orange,
   'saddle':    $color-saddle,
   'gold':      $color-gold,
   'ivory':     $color-ivory,
   'olive':     $color-olive
 );
```

Next, I want to start adding colors to this map, dynamically:

```
 $n : 'newcolor';
 $v : #ffffff;

 $mypalette: append($mypalette, ($n $v)); 

 @each $color in $mypalette {
    @debug $color;
 }
```

As you can see, both the name and the value of the newly item are dynamic, stored in a variable. Somewhat to my surprise, this works. The debug output does show the new value added correctly:

DEBUG: "sunset" #ff9800
DEBUG: "saddle" #8b4513
DEBUG: "gold" #ffd700
DEBUG: "ivory" #fffff0
DEBUG: "olive" #808000
DEBUG: "newcolor" #ffffff

The very last part is to actually use a value from list:

```
 html {
    background: map-get($mypalette, 'ivory') !important;
 }
```

Unfortunately, this is where it falls apart:

```
> error src/scss/main.scss (Line 401 of src/scss/_theme.scss: $map:
> (("jungle" #bbd910), ("sky" #2196f3), ("sunset" #ff9800), ("saddle"
> #8b4513), ("gold" #ffd700), ("ivory" #fffff0), ("olive" #808000), ("newcolor" #ffffff)) is not a map for `map-get')
```

It doesn't seem to matter which value of the map I am trying to look up, it always throws this error. Question on my mind is, is what I want to accomplish simply impossible or am I overlooking a basic syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to quote your keys, e.g:

```
$mypalette: (
   jungle: $color-green
);

map-get($mypalette, jungle);
```

Also you can use map-merge:

```
$new: (
    newcolor: #ffffff
);

map-merge($mypalette, $new);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Quoting the keys is done for safety since some of these colors are reserved CSS names. That said, unquoting them does not solve it, getting the same error. I haven't looked into map-merge yet, but the example you does not have a dynamic variable name.

Comment: I've done some more testing, and to my surprise map-merge on dynamically named variables, works:  $mypalette: map-merge($mypalette, ($n: $v)); where n and v are variables.

Comment: @Ferdy finnicky thing isn't it :)